# Child theme preview missing

Tags: child-theme

I followed the beginner steps for creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).  The child theme was created and it appears as an option on my Themes page. But unlike the other Themes on the page (including its parent), there is no preview.  The other themes ("Twenty Twelve," "Twenty Thirteen," and "Twenty Fourteen") are all listed with an image preview.  My child theme ("Twenty Fourteen Child") does not have any image. The child theme can be applied without issue.

This issue arises when I create child themes from other themes as well. Any ideas why this is happening and if I can resolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't covered in that codex page. These previews of the themes aren't auto generated. You will need to take a screenshot of your theme, and upload that screenshot to your root folder as 'screenshot.png'. This screenshot will be automatically used then as a theme preview pic for your theme.

I quote from the [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) page in the codex about screenshots for theme preview pic

> Create a screenshot for your theme. The screenshot should be named
>   screenshot.png, and should be placed in the top level directory. The
>   screenshot should accurately show the theme design and saved in PNG
>   format. The recommended image size is 880x660. The screenshot will
>   only be shown as 387x290, but the over double-sized image allows for
>   high-resolution viewing on HiDPI displays.

Comment: Did my question answer your problem. If so, please accept my answer by clicking on the check mark below the up/down arrows next to my answer. This will ensure that my answer not just help you, but others that will find this link. If not, is there anything regarding your question I can help with?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Sorry for the late reply--I don't think I received an email notification regarding your answer.